# Separate administrators access to different django admin sites

Tags: django, django-admin

Assume there is a Django application with several admin sites. Each is meant to be used by different people.

If a user is marked as "is_staff", he gets access to all admin sites by default.

The question is: how to disallow an administrator of one AdminSite to access another AdminSite?